# Return False wont read the next IF Statement?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make my text boxes red when the value is null. Unfortunately when I submit the form only the text box `emp_id` turns red and the `emp_fn` remains the same. I think this is because of the `return false` function. What do you think. Btw Im a newbie

```
function emp_add_validate() {
    var emp_id = document.emp_add.emp_id.value;
    var emp_fn = document.emp_add.emp_fn.value;
    if (emp_id == null || emp_id == ""){
        document.getElementById("emp_id").classList.add("is-invalid");
        return false;
    }
    if (emp_fn == null || emp_fn == ""){
        document.getElementById("emp_fn").classList.add("is-invalid");
        return false;
    }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
}
```

Comment: Can you add this code on codepen. Its easy to debug there. Or add code snippet ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you meant to return `false` if either if-test fails, but only after you have performed both tests:

```
function emp_add_validate() {
  var emp_id = document.emp_add.emp_id.value;
  var emp_fn = document.emp_add.emp_fn.value;
  var ok = true;
  if (emp_id == null || emp_id == "") {
    document.getElementById("emp_id").classList.add("is-invalid");
    ok = false;
  }
  if (emp_fn == null || emp_fn == "") {
    document.getElementById("emp_fn").classList.add("is-invalid");
    ok = false;
  }
  return ok;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is because of the `return` keyword.

> The return statement ends function execution and specifies a value to be returned to the function caller.

[from mdn web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return)

What happen is when the first `if` block is executed it saw the `return` keyword and exits the function which makes the second `if` to not get executed.

You can refractor your code by having the `return false` statement outside of the `if` block.

```
function emp_add_validate() {
var emp_id = document.emp_add.emp_id.value;
var emp_fn = document.emp_add.emp_fn.value;
if (emp_id == null || emp_id == ""){
    document.getElementById("emp_id").classList.add("is-invalid");
}
if (emp_fn == null || emp_fn == ""){
    document.getElementById("emp_fn").classList.add("is-invalid");
}            
return false;
```

}